# Which archiving method is better for compressing text files on Linux?

Tags: linux, zip, gzip, bzip2

In my application I need do compress of logs that are text files.

Seems that `bzip2` and `gzip` have the same compression ratio.

Is that correct?

Comment: xz (from xz-tools or 7z from p7zip, it is very like lzma) is the best. bzip2 is better than gzip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, bz2 has a better compression ratio, combined with better recoverability features.

OTOH, gz is faster.

xz is said to be even better than bz2, but I don't know the timing behaviour.

Comment: xz is slower than bzip2.

Comment: xz is  not just slower , but  much slower, 300 mb file took about 30 seconds for bzip2 to compress. I killed xz after it had been compressing for longer than 5 minutes

Comment: @Копать_Шо_я_нашел I think it depends heavily on the compression level you choose. With `-1`, it is not so very slow, but with the default settings, it tends to be quite slow.

Answer (score 13):

Last update of [maximumcompression.com](http://www.maximumcompression.com/) is June-2011 <sub>(answer updated in Oct-2015)</sub>
Therefore this website does not mention
the current **champion text compressor worldwide**:

## [**`cmix`**](http://www.byronknoll.com/cmix.html)

Competitions/Benchmarks:

- [**enwiki6**](http://compressionratings.com/sort.cgi?s_enwik6.full+4n)
  18.2% compression of the *1MB text file enwik6*
- [**Calgary**](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/#benchmarks)
  17.6% compression of the *14 files of the Calgary corpus* (3GB tar file)
- [**Hutter Prize**](http://prize.hutter1.net/)
  15.7% compression of the *100MB text file enwik8*
  (but `cmix` is not the winner because requires too much RAM, more than 20GB)
- [**Silesia Open Source Compression Benchmark**](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/silesia.html)
  15.7% compression of the [*202MB  Silesia corpus*](http://sun.aei.polsl.pl/~sdeor/index.php?page=silesia)
- [**Large Text Compression Benchmark**](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text.html)
  12.4% compression of the *1GB text file enwik9*

**Details:**
[Byron Knoll](http://www.byronknoll.com/) is actively developping `cmix` as libre software (GPL) since 2013 based on the book [Data Compression Explained](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/dce.html) by [Matt Mahoney](http://mattmahoney.net/). Matt Mahoney also maintains some of the above benchmarks and proposes [ZPAQ](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaq.html) ([WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZPAQ)), a command line incremental archiver.

---

If you prefer a more standard tool (requiring less RAM) I recommend:

## [**`lrzip`**](https://github.com/ckolivas/lrzip)

`lrzip` is an evolution of [`rzip`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rzip#lrzip) by [Con Kolivas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Con_Kolivas).
`lrzip` stands for two names: *Long Range ZIP* and *Lzma RZIP*.
`lrzip` is often better than `xz` (another popular compression tool).
[Alexander Riccio](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/43211/alexander-riccio) also recommends `lrzip`.

---

My favorite is:

## [**`zpaq`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZPAQ)

The *"archiver expert"*, [Matt Mahoney](http://mattmahoney.net/), has intensively worked on [PAQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAQ) algorithms for ten years and provide the best compromise between CPU/memory resources and compression level.

However, the [last `zpaq` version](https://github.com/zpaq/zpaq/releases) is not often packaged/available on recent distro :-(
I always compile it from sources when I have a new machine and I need a very good compressor: https://github.com/zpaq/zpaq

```
clone https://github.com/zpaq/zpaq
cd zpaq
g++ -O3 -march=native -Dunix zpaq.cpp libzpaq.cpp -pthread -o zpaq
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could have a look to [those benchmarks](http://www.maximumcompression.com/index.html), especially the part testing the [log files compression](http://www.maximumcompression.com/data/log.php).

Comment: Link does not work.

Answer (score 4):

i have made a benchmark to test to compress the following: 
**204MB folder** (with  1,600 html files)
**results**

```
7zip =>     2.38 MB
winrar =>   49.5 MB
zip =>      50.8 MB
gzip =>     51.9 MB
```

so the 7zip is the best among them 
you can get it from here 
http://www.7-zip.org/

Answer (score 0):

bz2 has tighter compression, the algorithm has more options to look for redundancy to compress away.

gzip is in much more tools, and is more cross platform. More Windows tools can deal with .gz files. It's part of http, so even web browsers can understand it.

On linux, there are tools that let you work on compressed files directly. zgrep and bzgrep can search in compressed files.

If just on Linux, I'd use bzip2, for the slightly better compression ratios.

Answer (score 0):

xz compresses much better than bz2, but takes more time.  So, if maximum compression is your goal and space on your hard drive is at a premium (which is my case with one drive at 98% full - while I reorganize my file systems), and you can fire off a script to do the work - take a break and come back in 5 minutes.

unxz is very fast to uncompress in my experience - which is a good thing for me on a daily basis.

bz2 is faster to compress than xz, but does not appear to achieve the compression results of xz.

The only way to make these assessments is to run benchmarks against a mix of common files you normally would compress/decompress, and vary the parameters to see which comes out on top.

Answer (score 0):

if you care more about compression ratio than compression speed, then
brotli is the best I found so far.

I have a 2MB text file and brotli compressed it twice as better (half size) than bzip2,gzip could do.

from linux **apt install brotli** and check for yourself.